# Test cases failing on Firebase Test Lab but works on local machine

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, kotlin, firebase-test-lab

I have written AndroidUnitTest for custom views. They work fine on local but crashes on FTL with

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details
```

On Firebase Console under Test Issues Tab, it's showing this.

```
     *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'generic/gce_x86_phone/gce_x86:9/PGR1.190916.001/5877764:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 7369, tid: 7436, name: tiDexTestRunner  >>> com.domain.debug <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'field.cc:78] Check failed: art_field != nullptr '
    eax 00000000  ebx 00001cc9  ecx 00001d0c  edx 00000006
    edi 00001cc9  esi 0000022e
    ebp 000607c1  esp c6298908  eip f4ca8be9
```

And on checking logs, I found this error.

```
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210): evo: Failed to dump cda
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean cxn.a(android.content.Context, java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.search.nativecard.FeatureCardNoticeExtension.a(PG:132)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at cda.a(PG:352)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at evo.a(PG:20)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at bgm.a(PG:2502)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.a(PG:573)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at bgm.dump(PG:2496)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:151)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
08-04 22:01:33.432: E/AndroidIME(2210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-04 22:01:33.498: E/memtrack(2076): Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Any custom views don't have EditText to take keyboard inputs.
Any suggestions where should I look for the errors?

I am using [Mockk](https://mockk.io/) for mocking objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hoe about run in PIxel3 (API 28) or Pixel2(API 29)? Is it still work?

Comment: @Desmond Yes it works on Local Emulator but fails in FTL